# How to have JavaScript manipulate all LI elements, not just one?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get this event listener to listen to all LI items and not just the first one in the list?

HTML:

```
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="nav-items"><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li class="nav-items"><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="nav-items"><a href="#socials">Socials</a></li>
    </ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
const navItem = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-items");

navItem.addEventListener("click", () =>{
   navLinks.classList.remove("nav-active");
   burger.classList.remove("toggle");
   body.classList.remove("fixed-position");
});
```

da

Comment: you need to loop it and add the event to each item. Several ways to loop, here's a classic/simple one: `for (var i = 0; i < navItem.length; i++) { navItem[ 
i ].addEventListener('click', function( e ) { console.log( 'clicked on nav-item number: ' + i, ' and the e passed to the event-handler is the click-event which triggered it', e ) } ); }`. Since this question has been answered elsewhere i'd recommend you delete it before it gets downvotes into oblivion, good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a list of dom nodes, not a single node. So, assuming you won't ever add additional nav-links added after the execution of your javascript, you just need to iterate over each element in the list, and add an event listener.

```
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-items");

navItems.forEach(navItem=> {
  navItem.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    navLinks.classList.remove("nav-active");
    burger.classList.remove("toggle");
    body.classList.remove("fixed-position");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your nav-links class to be a delegate so you only have one event listener.

```js
const navItem = document.querySelector(".nav-links");

navItem.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target.href) {
    console.log(event.target);
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li class="nav-items"><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items"><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items"><a href="#socials">Socials</a></li>
</ul>
```